# LoadLibrary access violation

Tags: dll

when I try to LoadLibrary getting an error message 988 (access violation)
this dll is not mine
all what i know it has been builded with borland c++ 
I am trying to solve this problem for several weeks
Help me please!

Comment: show the relevant code where you call LoadLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dll to see if it needs some other dll's to load.

Comment: i was trying dependency walker but as i can see no other dll is needed
also i'm trying to disassembly code with IDA disassembler without any success
only one thing what i saw it's memory allocation in DllMain...